Cmake refuses to use the appropriate header path (macOS)
I am trying to compile a library that uses libpng, which I have installed as a homebrew package. When using find_package, the correct library version (1.6.44) is selected (at /opt/homebrew), but the wrong headers are selected (1.4.12). The headers are taken from /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework.
If I rename the Headers subdirectory in the Mono framework, it works just fine. Now I am trying to somehow tell CMake to take the correct headers. I have tried the following before calling find_package(PNG 1.6.44 REQUIRED):
set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Headers)
set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Headers/libpng14)
set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PREFIX_PATH /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /opt/homebrew)
set(PNG_DIR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng)

All to no avail. It still takes the wrong headers from /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Headers/libpng14 instead of /opt/homebrew/include/libpng16. The only thing that works is renaming the Mono subfolder, which is obviously a bad solution... What am I doing wrong?
EDIT:
Output from CMake when the Mono folder is NOT moved out of the way:
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find PNG: Found unsuitable version "1.4.12", but required is at
  least "1.6.44" (found /opt/homebrew/lib/libpng.dylib)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:598 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.27.8/share/cmake/Modules/FindPNG.cmake:177 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  external/irrlicht-sdl2/CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)

If it IS moved out of the way (i.e. if there are fewer places to look), CMake seems to find the newer version in the homebrew tree without problems.
EDIT 2 / possible solution
I found a solution, or workaround:
Apparently the mono issue is well-known. It can be circumvented by using set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK LAST) to tell cmake to consider system frameworks (including ono with the outdated libpng) only after other locations (such as homebrew). In my case this seems to work and not produce any side effects.

What exactly do you mean by "the wrong headers are selected"? Have you read PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS variable after the find_package(PNG) call and found it to contain /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Headers/libpng14 directory? Or it is just a compiler which picks the wrong header? Variables like CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH affects only on the result of find_path call (which is performed inside FindPNG.cmake module). If this call returns /opt/homebrew/include/libpng16 but a compiler picks the header from another directory, then it is completely different problem.

@Tsyvarev when the Mono folder is NOT moved out of the way, CMake says Could NOT find PNG: Found unsuitable version "1.4.12", but required is at   least "1.6.44" (found /opt/homebrew/lib/libpng.dylib) (btw that dylib is a symlink to the actual 1.6.44 dylib) - this means that CMake's find_package looks in the Mono folder regardless what I do (unless the folder is not actually there) and then stops looking and complains that it cannot find 1.6.44; however if the folder is not there it looks in the homebrew tree and finds it. in short: it very much seems to be a CMake issue

Please, incorporate that output into the question post. Exact error message is important part of the problem.
